# How to plot rectangular slices in a barchart ? coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot, bar-chart

How to plot rectangular slices in a barchart ? The slice can be plotted anywhere. It should not start from xAxis.

This slice is actually pointing to a corresponding x and y value.The width of the slice remains same as the bars plotted in the barchart.The height is set a very small value to see it as a slice.

[image]

The Blue colored is bar chart's bar and brown colored is the slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `barBasesVary` to `YES` on the bar plot. This will cause the plot to query the datasource for an additional field called `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`. The base value defines one end of the bar and the tip value defines the other end. The location determines the horizontal placement (for vertical bars) as always.